# birchas hatorah if one isn't going to learn

Tags: torah-study, petur-exemption, birchos-hatorah

Does one have a chiyuv to say birchas hatorah if he isn't going to learn anyway that day?

Comment: Welcome to J.SE 109283874756564883987899257547. Hope to see you around (and no, I did not just type all those numbers out).

Answer (score 5):

There is a chiyuv (obligation) to learn Torah each day, so one already has a chiyuv to say birchas haTorah.

Comment: This answer would only apply to men. The question seems to be worded in the masculine, so this answer is straight and to the point.

Comment: But aren't there some forms of talmud torah that we don't say birkat hatorah for? So what if you only plan on doing those that day?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless, I assume you'll be saying the bits of Bible and Talmud (Yevarech'cha Hashem ... Eilu devarim sh'ayn lahem shiur ... eilu devarim she'adam ochel) that come right after the blessings?  That's Torah.  The Shema?  That's Torah.  Without trying, you'll wind up reciting some Torah sooner or later!

But yes, it's part of the daily blessings no matter what you intend to do that day, so say birchas hatorah.

It's even suggested that our entire daily routine is considered one extended act of "involvement in Torah", as how you eat, work, talk -- are all governed by Torah.  (Hence only one bracha needed per day.)  Or as one yeshiva put it: "some yeshivas think Torah is everything.  We think everything is Torah."

Comment: Sources [15 char]?

Comment: Note that the berakhot befre shema cover for birkhot haTorah for shema, and possibly for the whole day. The classical case of birkhat haTorah in the morning is for one who arose early to learn Torah before prayer.

Comment: What does being governed by Torah have to do with birkhot haTorah? I think you are understanding sources like Tosafot in Berakhot...

Answer (score 1):

Shulhan Aruch Y"D 246 says one must learn Torah, no matter what their financial position. In some siddurim they bring some baraytot and pesukim to say to fulfill this obligation.

Comment: Let's say someone is an avel, and exempt from the normal obligation, or will learn mentally, which does not require a blessing? This just dodges the question.